# use python request to load more items

Tags: python, request, web-crawler

Im a beginner python programmer.I want to crawl all sport news in   [skySports](https://www.skysports.com/news-wire) website. I created a python request to load more items. I used inspect element in chrome to see the [XHR details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOEh1.png).

My python Code is shown as below :

```
import requests
import json
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False

url = 'https://zagent891.h-cdn.com/cmd/get_links_info?customer=sky_uk&zone=gen&ver=1.113.763&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.skysports.com%2Fnews-wire'

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://www.skysports.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.skysports.com/news-wire',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'
}

params={
    'customer': 'sky_uk',
    'zone': 'gen',
    'ver': '1.113.763',
    'url': 'https://www.skysports.com/news-wire'

}
response = session.get(url,headers=headers,params=params)
print(response.json())
```

When I run this code I get this Error :

```
{'error': 'wrong zone'}
```

how can I send this request to load more items and then crawl the news.

Comment: Do you want just the news snippets or the entire article?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module in python to scrape the web. It is specially designed for web scraping. Here you can find the example code. https://github.com/Hemil96/Brainyquote-API/blob/master/scrap.py

Comment: thanks for your answer. Im using beautifulSoup as well but it cant handle ajax webpages. I want to click on show more items and beautifulsoup cant do this.

Comment: Okay, I see, Please check below the article. It may help.
https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/how-to-scrape-an-ajax-website-using-python-qw8fuitvi